# Call multiple time JNI in single Tread

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to call some methods from a jar using JNI in c++.But i need to call it a lot of times in different instances of thesame class.
My JNI is something like this

```
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
jmethodID Sim_constr = NULL;
jmethodID Read_XML = NULL;
jmethodID configure = NULL;
jmethodID initial = NULL;
jmethodID results = NULL;
jint step = 60;
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<My jar>";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */`

long status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
if (status == JNI_ERR){
    exit(10);
}
//Some Java method Calls... `
```

I need to set once the JNI and then just call 3-4 methods OR to kill/delete completely the JNI parameters and then create it again.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your goal.  Are you just spinning off new JVM's?  Where are the native threads?  How do they interact with each other?

Comment: I just need to call a Java method (using JNI) in my c++ project many times through different instances of a class. E.g MyClass obj1,obj2.Call jar method with obj1...fine,call method with obj2...not possible because in the first instance a JVM has already been created.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you may try to accomplish the following

After creating a JVM using CreateJavaVM method your JVM remains Global for all instance of the class, the environment variable(env) should be local for each instance of the class. And also env var for each instance must be used to call your methods many times using different instances.

This snippet will get you the env from JVM:(place this such that every instance has local copy of env and global copy of jvm)

After creating the instance you have to attach these env to the current thread(i.e current instance)

```
JNIEnv * g_env;
 int getEnvStat = jvm->GetEnv((void **)&g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_8);

 if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
  printf("GetEnv: not attached");
  getEnvStat = g_vm->AttachCurrentThread((void **) &g_env, NULL);
  if ( getEnvStat != 0) {
   printf("Failed to attach");
  }
 } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_OK) {
 } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {
  printf("GetEnv: version not supported");
 }
//use the g_env variable for java method calls
//Rememeber to use this code as a local copy for each instance
```

Comment: I did it by creating a JNI env and passing this pointer to any class through Global Environment variable.So i create just once the JVM and then i can use all the functions at every instance ;)

Comment: so the same JNI env variable is used across all instances?

Comment: Yes exactly,so this way i can use the Java Virtual Machine Methods anywhere

Comment: It is not advised to use JNI env variable as a global pointer for all threads see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html). Thats why i suggested using Global JVM and local JNI env for each instance in use.

Comment: I agree but i have only one single Thread all i do is to start the JVM in a Class and use it multiple times in another class.Although if anything will raise up i will keep in mind your solution.